# IE keyboard scrolling inside HTML5 semantic elements

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, overflow

I'm developing an internal web app for my organization, written in PHP. Unfortunately, HTML and CSS are not among my specialties, so I have to teach myself a lot of the presentation side as I go.

I want to implement a basic scrolling box with some content in it. For the most part I've gotten it working. However I can't use the *keyboard* with IE (9, 10, 11) to scroll inside an HTML5 semantic element (`section`, `article`, `nav`, etc). A regular `div` works fine. Firefox and Chrome have no problems regardless of the element.

To be clear, the scroll bar is visible, active, and functions properly when directly manipulated (i.e. clicked or dragged). The mouse scroll-wheel also scrolls just fine. Only the keyboard arrows seems to be an issue. I could just shrug and abandon the HTML5 semantic tags entirely (having no functional use for them beyond readability), but I'd rather figure out what's wrong.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly, or have I hit an IE bug that requires a workaround? I've tried searching/experimenting for hours and can't seem to find a solution.

**CSS**

```
.scrollable {
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="scrollable">
    IE <em>can not</em> keyboard scroll this.<br />
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<div class="scrollable">
    IE <em>can</em> keyboard scroll this.<br />
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like IE has forgotten to made these new elements focusable, when they're having scrollbar(s). You can fix the issue by adding a `tabindex` to `section` tag, works at least for IE10.

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9U9kD/1/).

Comment: Awesome, that does it. I would never have thought to try that.